# 'Give you notice' vs 'Give you a notice'

Tags: word-choice

Which form of the following sentence is correct:

**We wanted to give you notice...**

*or*

**We wanted to give you a notice...**

Comment: Why do you think only one would be correct?

Comment: @curiousdannii depending on the context.

Comment: @Skovy You acknowledge the meaning depends on context, yet you provide no context. Both forms can be correct.

Comment: @choster Sorry, I asked the question unclearly. I wanted to know which was correct in what circumstances or context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both correct; it just depends on the context.

- **A** notice is a concrete noun and might refer/often refers to a piece of paper with information on it.
- "Notice" on its own is an abstract noun and is a warning about a future event.

See: [Definition of notice](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/notice?s=t)